# Using \printeranswers environment, how to print solutions in the box without the title "Solutions"

Tags: exam

I'm creating some worksheets/problem sets for a high school pre-alg class and have included the option to print solutions.

Is it possible to print the answers in a box **without the title "SOLUTIONS".**

I searched for an answer in stackexchange and also reviewed section 8 of Hirschhorn's *Using the exam document class.*

Either I'm not understanding the "exam doc" class or there's an error in my code that forces the title "solution" to print in every answer box. In the hope that one of you generous souls will take pity on me and provide a solution for this issue, I have posted the relevant portion of my code below.

Many thanks to all of you who take time to read this post!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

%\printanswers % uncomment to print solutions.
\printanswers
% MACROS
%Not sure all of these packages are necessary...but the 'taks package is certainly necessary
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption} % allows captions in minipage envir (issue w/solutions envir)
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{framed} %box para
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
%\displaystyle for all $$ math environments use \lim\limits for other environments

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

%\unframedsolutions % uncomment to remove boxes from solutions
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % removes paragraph indentation

\pagestyle{head}
\header{Pre-Alg Pd #5: Exponent Concepts Covered in Class on 04-04-19 (D11)}
       {}
       {04/05/19} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
  \makebox[\textwidth]{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}\par
  \vspace{4mm}
  \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule}{
    \textbf {Simplify by expansion and steps shown in class. Your answer should have only POSITIVE EXPONENTS.
     \bigskip
    \\Show all work/steps on this page.}


  }}}\par
  \bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\settasks{after-item-skip=15em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=2em,
          item-indent=3em,
          %change '1' to 'a' if you want letters instead of numbers
          counter-format=(tsk[1]),
          column-sep=2em
          }



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% -------------------------- DOCUMENT STARTS HERE -------------------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
https://www.overleaf.com/project/5ca66096f91606440362a785
\pagetop

\begin{tasks}(2)

% Prob #1
\task $4y\cdot 2y^3\cdot3x^{-2}$
\begin{solution}
$4^1$
\end{solution}

% Prob #2
\task $4xy^0\cdot x^{-2}y^{-3}\cdot
y^0$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}

% Prob #3
\task $\frac{3y\cdot2xy^2}{3x^{-2}y^4}$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}

% Prob #4
\task $\frac{xy^{-3}}{3x^3y^{-2}\cdot2x^{-3}y}$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}

% Prob #5
\task $\frac{m^{-4}n^4\cdot(mn^2)\strut^{-3}}{(m^2n^4)\strut^0}$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}

\end{tasks}

\clearpage
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the rule:

```
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{THIS_IS_THE_WORD_YOU_WANT_TO_DELETE}
```

full code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\printanswers
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\begin{document} 
\begin{questions}
\question question1
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
Your answer 
\end{solutionorbox}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick and accurate response, Arne. Being a LaTeX newbie, the only that initially confused was the need to replace this code.....\begin{solution}
$4^1$
\end{solution}..... with \{solutionorbox} . Is there a global search and replace to speed up the process of revising the code in the way you suggest?

Comment: @WyoWindStorm I don't understand your problem. Sorry. But if if you place the renew command in the preamble. Every question where you use solutionorbox, solution, solutionordottedlines environment, when you choose for the the print answer option, there will be no 'solution' word in your answer.